# How to access fields in page within iframe?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, ssl

I have a .aspx page that contains an iframe.  I am drawing the embedded page from my ssl server.  When I try and modify fields with the embedded page with javascript (I am putting data into hidden fields so that I can use it server side to id the client) I get an access denied message.  If i run the whole thing locally I get no problems so really the question is what do I have to change on my ssl server in order to allow those fields to be altered?

The javascript is really straight forward:

```
            window.frames["frame1"].document.forms['password_form']["username"].value = document.getElementById("username").value;
```

and as i said works apart from when I change the iframe src to ssl...

It's a precompiled app, i'm wondering if that makes a difference.  The page itself is not read only.

Thanks, Ron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) prohibits scripting across documents from different origins. The protocol (HTTP/HTTPS) is part of the origin. Therefore the browser must prohibit access to `window.frames["frame1"].document` in your example if only iframe is on HTTPS.

The easy solution is to use HTTPS for both the main page and the iframe.

A workaround is possible, but depending on your needs it might be too much hassle: http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes (a long, but informative read).

Comment: Thanks Jakub.  I realized after doing a little research last week myself that I was actually trying to do cross site scripting which was not my intention.  This is the way my boss wants it set up!  So I am ultimately here to oblige...